Translation failed TypeError: google_translate_api_x__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a function
I attempted to run this code for my translation web app created from react:
import translate from 'google-translate-api-x';

export async function translateText(text, sourceLang, targetLang) {
  try {
    const response = await translate(`${text}`, {
      from: `${sourceLang}`, 
      to: `${targetLang}`, 
      autoCorrect: true
    });

    // Extract the translated text from the response
    return response.text;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during translation:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

It keeps giving me the error:
Translation failed TypeError: google_translate_api_x__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a function
I read the API README and copied the way that they have used the function and didn't get the same result. I think this problem may lie in
export async function
I am a JavaScript/React beginner so I do not have much knowledge on how to solve the issue.
